# General Solution Diff Eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(t)=Ce^{t^{2}}$ + 2 ($C$ is a constant) be the general solution of the differential equation $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$. Determine the functions of $p(t)$ and $g(t)$.

So what I did was found the derivative of $y(t)$ and I added my $y(t)+y'(t)$ and I got $-2t=p(t)$

And then got my general solution and got $-4t=g(t)$

So did I compute this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Put the derivative in the differential equation gives

$2Cte^{t^{2}}+Cp(t)e^{t^{2}}+2p(t)=g(t)$

You can solve the differential equation without right-hand side members to obtain an other equation in $p(t)$...

To solve the problem you can research the general solution of a linear differntial equation of the firts order to find how $g(t)$ and $p(t)$ influence the general solution and find equation to obtain $p$ and $g$...

Comment: Ok great! That is exactly what I did. Thank you.